# C++ what does <> tag mean

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a line of code that I found, I had never seen this before.

```
auto pnt_header = mem::read<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS>(base + dos_header.e_lfanew);
```

I am confused what this right here does

```
<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS>
```

If anyone can tell me what this tag right here does, like what does <> do. I don't know what its called so I couldn't look it up.

Comment: Look up C++ templates.

Comment: These are template arguments.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Comment: You only needed to finish reading your book!